# "disable" li of Bootstrap dropdown-menu while AJAX call executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ypj3ve6n/2/) which displays a bootstrap `.dropdown-menu`. `.stopPropagation()` is called on the dropdown menu's `click` event so that it remains open. Each `li` contains an `a` which corresponds to some AJAX function (which I simulate in this example using `setTimeout()`.

I would like for the `li` to be "unclickable" during the AJAX call so that the UI doesn't allow the users to spam the endpoint with unnecessary requests. For that, when the AJAX call is being made, I add a `.submitting` class to the current `li`, which is removed as soon as the call is complete, to use it as an identifier that an AJAX call is happening on this `li`. However I don't know how to actually "disable" the `li` during the AJAX submission.  As far as I'm aware there's no built-in way to "disable" the `li` while the call is being made.

```
$('ul.dropdown-menu.custom-list li.list-item.submitting').click(function(e) {
    return false; // doesn't work
});
```

How can I make the `li` unclickable during the AJAX call, and then back to clickable when the AJAX call is complete?

Edit: to be perfectly clear, I only want the **current `li`** to be unclickable, not all. So if I clicked `li` with index 0, then `li` with index 0 becomes unclickable while the AJAX call is happening. Once the AJAX call is complete, then `li` with index 0 becomes clickable again.

Comment: Care to explain the downvote and close requests? I defined my code in a JSFiddle, explained what I'm trying to accomplish, included a snippet of what I tried that didn't work. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/ypj3ve6n/4/

```js
/* Latest compiled and minified JavaScript included as External Resource */
$('.dropdown-menu').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});

$('ul.dropdown-menu.custom-list li.list-item').click(function(e) {
  console.log('item ' + $(this).text() + ' clicked');
  var listItem = $(this);
  listItem.addClass("submitting");
  $(this).css({
    'pointer-events': 'none'
  });
  var that = this;
  var millisecondsToWait = 4000;
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('complete');
    listItem.removeClass("submitting");
    $(that).css({
      'pointer-events': 'auto'
    });
  }, millisecondsToWait);
});
```

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */
@import url('//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

body {
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bootstrap 3</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown active">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Getting started <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download">Download Bootstrap</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">Examples</li>
                        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template">Basic template</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/starter-template/">Starter template</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/">Grids</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron/">Jumbotron</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/">Navbar</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/signin/">Sign-in page</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/">Sticky footer</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/">Offcanvas</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/">Carousel</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/theme/">Theme</a></li>                        
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">Compatibility</li>
                        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#migration">Migrating from 2.x to 3.0</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#browsers">Browser support</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#third-parties">Third party support</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/css">CSS</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/components">Components</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/javascript">JavaScript</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/customize">Customize</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
   
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Twitter Bootstrap 3.3.7</h1>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
            Dropdown
            <span class="caret"></span>
          </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu custom-list" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
        <li class="list-item"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Action</a></li>
        <li class="list-item"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Another action</a></li>
        <li class="list-item"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Something else here</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li class="list-item"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've used `css` property `pointer-events:none;` during the `Ajax` call.
Once the `Ajax` call is completed `pointer-events` will set back to `auto`.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi, see my update. I don't want all `li`s to be disabled, just the one which is currently doing an AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

Use below method to stop the propagation of executing click event

```
var text=0;
$('ul.dropdown-menu.custom-list li.list-item.submitting').click(function(e) {
    if(text==1)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: data,
            beforeSend: function() {
                text=1;
            },
            success: function(data) {
            text=0;
            }
        });
    }
});
```